# Eclipse - search for resource - limit extension to match .js NOT .jsp

Tags: eclipse, search, ide

In Eclipse, when I press Ctrl+Shift+R to bring up the 'Open resource' dialog window, I can't figure out a way of searching only for javascript files (.js), as any search string I enter will always yield .jsp files as well.

I tried `abc*.js` (explicit file extension does not work, as still JSPs are returned), `abc*.??` (trying to limit the length of extension to any TWO characters, still returns JSPs)... it's a bit annoying. Is there any way to get the window to return .js files only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, I managed to resolve this myself. It doesn't seem like the correct thing for Eclipse to do (naughty Eclipse, naughty, you should be ashamed of yourself) but it does work like a charm - it's as simple as typing a `<space>` after the search term.

So, instead of searching for "abc*.js" (which would yield .jsp results also), one can just type in "abc*.js " (followed by a space) and now only javascript files are presented in the results list. Voilà!

Comment: I just tried this on Indigo, and it just doesn't work. Adding the space doesn't remove the "*.js?" files like "*.jsp" or "*.jspx".

Answer (score 2):

I asked about this in the Eclipse forums, and found a [real solution](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1086703/#msg_1086703).